# Automation using VMWare Workstation

Tags: vmware, automation

I'm running an experiment that requires me to create 100 instances of Windows XP w/SP3 and saving each VM instance off to a hard drive.

I have to annotate the time that the VM load starts (starting my timer when I see the "Setup is preparing...") until the load ends when I see the final desktop after VM loads its drivers.  I also have to annotate the host start and stop time.

Is there any way this process can be automated?  Each load runs me about 16:00 minutes and gets real tiresome after a time. Exact timing is not necessary, eyeballing as described above is sufficient for my testing needs.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the VIX API.  It has COM bindings so you could use PowerShell or VBScript.

https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/